# How would the weather behave on a flat world with a stationary sun?

Tags: weather

I'm currently working on my first real project but I really don't know anything about weather patterns. The world I'm talking about is an infinite flat plain. In the center is a tall (~4000mi) tower with a bright lamp on top. The lamp periodically dims and brightens to simulate days and nights. Would there be convective cells? Would there be prevailing winds for sailing? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

A pretty simple set up results in a pretty simple result and convection currents, air will rise in the centre nearest your sun pushing air above to the sides where it falls as it cools pushing the air below to the centre where it's already being drawn by the lower pressure the rising air creates as it rises.

Prevailing winds near the ground move toward the centre.

Prevailing winds high above move away from the centre.

Most precipitation occurs around the edges as the air cools.

Comment: So, as I understand it, there would only be one cell?

Comment: If so, would it be possible for a spinning disc to have more than one sort of like a globe?

Comment: A spinning disk would result in the same type of weather that we have due to correolis effect, but the tropics would be in the center and the edges would be ice.